# Spring filter for extracting the body with ContentCachingResponseWrapper always returns 200

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-filter

I am trying to trace the HTTP requests and I created a filter using `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` and `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` in order to extract the payloads as well. It works fine as long as the request is handled successfully and the response code is 200.

But I realized that if something goes wrong and an error is thrown `responseWrapper.getStatusCode()` returns still 200 and the response body is empty. I see that frontend receives 500 and the error message in the body.

Here is my filter:

```
@Component
public class CustomHttpTraceFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private ContentTrace contentTrace;
    private final ContentTraceEvents contentTraceEvents;

    public CustomHttpTraceFilter(ContentTraceEvents contentTraceEvents) {
        this.contentTraceEvents = contentTraceEvents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        contentTrace = new ContentTrace();
        contentTrace.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        } finally {
            afterRequest(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        }

    }

    private void afterRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper, ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper) throws IOException {

        /*
         *  From Request Headers
         */

        String method = requestWrapper.getMethod();
        boolean isGetMethod = method.equals("GET");
        // At the moment get requests are not being tracked
        if (isGetMethod) {
            responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
            return;
        }

        contentTrace.setTimeTaken(System.currentTimeMillis() - contentTrace.timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond());
        contentTrace.setMethod(method);
        contentTrace.setRemoteAddress(requestWrapper.getRemoteAddr());
        contentTrace.setUri(requestWrapper.getRequestURI());

        contentTrace.setHost(requestWrapper.getHeader("host"));
        contentTrace.setAuthorization(requestWrapper.getHeader("authorization"));
        contentTrace.setUserAgent(requestWrapper.getHeader("user-agent"));
        contentTrace.setReferer(requestWrapper.getHeader("referer"));

        contentTrace.setReqBody(getRequestPayload(requestWrapper));

        /*
         *  From Response Headers
         */

        contentTrace.setStatus(responseWrapper.getStatusCode());

        contentTrace.setResBody(getResponsePayload(responseWrapper));

        /*
         * Important to copy the original response body, because it is removed.
         */

        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

        // publish event
        contentTraceEvents.publishContentTrace(contentTrace);
    }


    private String getRequestPayload(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapper =
                WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, ContentCachingRequestWrapper.class);
        if (wrapper != null) {
            byte[] buf = wrapper.getContentAsByteArray();
            if (buf.length > 0) {
                int length = buf.length;
                try {
                    return new String(buf, 0, length, wrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                    return "[unknown]";
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    private String getResponsePayload(ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse) {
        try {
            if (wrappedResponse.getContentSize() <= 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return new String(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray(), 0,
                    wrappedResponse.getContentSize(),
                    wrappedResponse.getCharacterEncoding());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "Could not read cached response body: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using **OncePerRequestFilter**.

The response body only comes with data on success responses **200**.

For error response status **400** & **500**, the response body is blank.

Looking for **DistpatcherType**, I found the following:

```
public enum DispatcherType {
    FORWARD,
    INCLUDE,
    REQUEST,
    ASYNC,
    ERROR;

    private DispatcherType() {
    }
}
```

I am not 100% sure about that, but I think that ERROR **DispatcherType** occurs in a different thread and is not caught by **OncePerRequestFilter**. You try to use **FilterRegistrationBean** to forge all **DispatcherTypes** but it does not work with **OncePerRequestFilter**. Using **GenericFilterBean** it works.

```
registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```

I will continue looking for a working solution using **OncePerRequestFilter** approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the template of using `OncePerRequestFilter` and `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`:

```
public class YourFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  ...

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                  FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = wrapRequest(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = wrapResponse(response);
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    } finally {
      if (!isAsyncStarted(requestWrapper)) {
        // read requestWrapper or responseWrapper
        responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilterAsyncDispatch() {
    return false;
  }

  private static ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrapRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request instanceof ContentCachingRequestWrapper) {
      return (ContentCachingRequestWrapper) request;
    } else {
      return new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    }
  }

  private static ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrapResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (response instanceof ContentCachingResponseWrapper) {
      return (ContentCachingResponseWrapper) response;
    } else {
      return new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```